# Programmatically get pending changes for a specific folder in a specific project?

Tags: c#

I have been playing around with TFS for a while because I need to upload/check in specific files and folders into various locations on the TFServer after they have been created and placed locally. I am mapping the workspace and everything and I get a bunch of changes from PendingChanges but not the ones I want and not where I want. The problem is really annoying because for every check in process I only want to work on a specific folder or file in a specific location that is already mapped. I am gonna paste part of the code here for reference.

```
using (TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri, _cred))
        {
            VersionControlServer versionControl = (VersionControlServer)collection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));


            string machineName = Environment.MachineName;
            string currentUserName = Environment.UserName;

            Workspace myWorkspace = versionControl.GetWorkspace(machineName, currentUserName);
            // tried this from Stack but didn't work.
            //PendingChange[] changes = myWorkspace.GetPendingChanges().Where(x => x.LocalOrServerFolder.Contains(localPath)).ToArray();

            PendingChange[] changes = myWorkspace.GetPendingChanges();
            if (changes.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach (PendingChange c in changes)
                {
                    rt.Text += "  path: " + c.LocalItem + ", change: " + PendingChange.GetLocalizedStringForChangeType(c.ChangeType) + "\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rt.Text += "This didn't work.";
            }
```

}

Basically I want to throw a folder or file at my TFS class and let it check if the file or folder is up to date or present on the TFS and act accordingly. I hope I have described the problem thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

I think that my answer will not response fully you question, but if you want to get pending changes for a specific folder, you can use something like this..

```
PendingChange[] changes = myWorkspace.GetPendingChanges(localPath, RecursionType.Full, false);
```